# Meaning of $u(t)$ in $x'(t)=f(x(t),u(t))$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

For a first order ODE we have the forms

> \begin{align}
> x'(t)&=f(x(t)) \\
> x'(t)&=f(t,x(t))
> \end{align}

However, I have also seen ODE:s with a second function $u$, i.e.

> \begin{align}
> x'(t)&=f(x(t),u(t)) \\
> x'(t)&=f(t,x(t),u(t))
> \end{align}

Wwhat is the meaning of $u$ in the function $f$?

Thanks!

Comment: In the former form there is no explicit time-dependence in the ODE (so it can be integrated directly) while in the second there can be explicit time-dependence meaning it's a harder equation to solve. Also I would write it as  $x'(t) = f(x(t), t)$ assuming $u(t)$ is meant to be a general function.

Comment: @Winther The latter form is often used in control theory where $u(t)$ corresponds to a control signal. The way how system depends on control signal is important so for their needs it's better not to fold $f(x(t), u(t))$ into a $\hat{f}(x(t), t)$.

Comment: Just a side note. I think that the letter $u$ is maybe used because the voltage is the input in many electro-mechanical systems.